# How would Einstein calculate acceleration of a ball?

Tags: general-relativity

Let's say that we have two homogeneous spherical balls - one with mass $m_1=1000m$ and radius $r_1=1000r$ and second with mass $m$ and radius $r$. Distance between centers of this balls is $R>1100r$. The balls are not moving(Their relative velocities are equal to $0$). Can equations of relativity theory be applied to problem of finding relative acceleration of a balls? If yes, then how exactly?

Comment: What is their acceleration from the observer's frame of reference?

Comment: They are not moving.

Comment: Then there relative velocities is 0

Comment: This seems to be just the [two body problem in GR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-body_problem_in_general_relativity).

Comment: they are moving, meaning that they always describe a curve (a geodesic) in a 4-dimensional manifold. Also, the more massive one would probably better be used as a source of a Schwarzschild metric affecting the other. You just need to check the geodesic equations for this metric in any book on GR. Also, you can't switch off gravity, they will fall into one another.